# log4j2 Delete on Rollover

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

I read the official document of log4j2 and get a question about RollingFileAppender.

That's what the document says:

Below is a sample configuration that uses a RollingFileAppender with both the time and size based triggering policies, ***will create up to 100 archives on the same day (1-100)*** that are stored in a directory based on the current year and month, and will compress each archive using gzip and will roll every hour. During every rollover, this configuration will delete files that match "*/app-*.log.gz" and are 30 days old or older, but keep the most recent 100 GB or the most recent 10 files, whichever comes first.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${baseDir}/app.log"
          filePattern="${baseDir}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100">
        <!--
        Nested conditions: the inner condition is only evaluated on files
        for which the outer conditions are true.
        -->
        <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
          <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz">
            <IfLastModified age="30d">
              <IfAny>
                <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="100 GB" />
                <IfAccumulatedFileCount exceeds="10" />
              </IfAny>
            </IfLastModified>
          </IfFileName>
        </Delete>
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I think this configuration will create up to 100 archives **on the same hour of the day,** not 100 archives **on the same day**, can anybody who give me a hand?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will keep up to 100 files in the hour but in reality it will never get that high since it is only keeping a maximum of 10 files overall.